# Simple Elevate Zoom plugin not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need serious help with my code. I am pretty new to JavaScript so it could be something really simple.

I want to use a Jquery plugin called [ElevateZoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples).

I downloaded the plugin, linked the jquery and elevatezoom files (jquery is working fine) and copied the demo's code. The demo works fine, so what I do not get is on the exact same browser but on my page it does not work. I have been scratching my head for at least 3 hours over this and tried multiple things such as implementing the scripts internally, trying different versions of jquery, using different images etc. My HTML and JavaScript code is below (note my first block of javascript works):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="Jeff/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Jeff/script.js"></script>
        <script src="Jeff/jquery.elevatezoom.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="logo"></div>

        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="deals.html">Deals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="store.html" style="font-size: 30px; color: #FFD700;">Store</a></li>
                    <li><a href="basket.html">Basket</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Coming soon</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Support</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>

        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="content">
                <br>


                    <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
                <hr>

                <div class="contentbox-big2" style="margin-left: 0px;">
                <div class="titlebox">
                    ADS
                    <div class="titleinfo"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="newscontent">

                <img src="img/brit.png" alt="image" style="width:167px;height:258px;">
                <br> <br> <hr> <br> <br>
                <img src="img/coke.jpg" alt="image" style="width:167px;height:258px;">
                <hr>


              </div>
           </div>


          <div class="contentbox-big3" style="margin-left: 0px;">
                <div class="titlebox">
                    Deals
                    <div class="titleinfo"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="newscontent2">
                <img id="zoom_01" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/0/06/Sun_EN_boxart.png/250px-Sun_EN_boxart.png"  data-zoom-image="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/0/06/Sun_EN_boxart.png/250px-Sun_EN_boxart.png"/>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Pokemon Sun 3DS - £14.99. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Add to basket: <img src="img/basket.png" alt="image" style="width:50px;height:50px;" onclick = "myFunction()">
                <br> <br> <hr> <br> <br>
                <hr>

                <img src="https://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/Notebooks/News/_nc3/20171029_pubg_logo.jpg" alt="image" style="width:300px;height:350px;">
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Player Unknown's Battlegrounds - £19.99. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Add to basket: <img src="img/basket.png" alt="image" style="width:50px;height:50px;" onclick = "myFunction()">
                <br> <br> <hr> <br> <br>
                <hr>

                <img src="http://sm.ign.com/t/ign_in/cover/b/battlefiel/battlefield-1_9ufa.250.jpg" alt="image" style="width:300px;height:350px;">
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Battlefield 1 - £24.99. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Add to basket: <img src="img/basket.png" alt="image" style="width:50px;height:50px;" onclick = "myFunction()">
                <br> <br> <hr> <br> <br>
                <hr>


           </div>   
        </div>
          </div>
            </div>

        <div class="footer"></div>

                  </div>
    </body>
 </div>

 <div class="soundcloud"> 
            <iframe width="100%" height="80" scrolling="no"  
frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/184695140&amp;color=%23ff5500&amp;auto_play=true&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;show_teaser=true&amp;visual=true"></iframe>

</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function myFunction() {
    if (window.confirm('If you click "ok" you will be taken to your shopping cart')) {
        window.location.href='basket.html';
    };
}

function myFunction() {
if (window.confirm('If you click "ok" you will be taken to your shopping cart')) {
        window.location.href='basket.html';
    };
}

$('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({
  zoomType: "inner",
  cursor: "crosshair",
  zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
  zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
});
```

Comment: Telling people to respond ASAP is really bad taste, and is not likely going to get you the help you are after.

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: @j08691 hi, turns out I get this - https://gyazo.com/66b567edb33bdc0b95e630649cad7ae8

Comment: Seems like your elevatezoom script isn't loading. Are you sure the path is correct and the file exists? Check your browser's network tab as well.

Comment: @j08691 thanks for the quick reply, and yes the path is definitely correct, the network tab looks like this but I don't really understand it https://gyazo.com/abedbdd97278c94df37232c9d01372e0

Comment: On the network tab you want to see what the status code of the elevatezoom script is.

Comment: @j08691 https://gyazo.com/e3dd3c59a2947ea66a182d1cd9cde49d

Comment: @j08691 after a bit I reordered it so that I called the elevatezoom file first, now there is no error in the console, but it is still not working, any thoughts?

Comment: Try to use the absolute path of the script and not relative one.